# GuzzleHTTP Request Error for VismaSign PHP

Tags: php, php-curl, guzzle

This is the error I am receiving from function authMiddleware() with GuzzleHttp. I am using this for VismaSign and receiving these errors. I am not sure what exactly is the issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   app\handlers\integrations\VismaSign::authMiddleware() must be an
>   instance of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request, instance of
>   GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack given.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace app\handlers\integrations;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

class VismaSign {

    const API_URL = "https://sign.visma.net/api/v1/";
    const CLIENT_IDENTIFIER = "ddf58116-6082-4bfc-a775-0c0bb2f945ce";
    const SECRET_KEY = "jp7SjOOr4czRTifCo30qx0sZAIw9PW+vVpsbP09pQaY=";

    private $client;
    private $clientHandler;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->clientHandler = $this->client->getConfig('handler');
    }

    public function authMiddleware(Request $request) {
        $request = new Request('POST', 'https://httpbin.org/post');

        //return $request->withHeader('Authorization', $this->authorizationHeader(self::CLIENT_IDENTIFIER, base64_decode(self::SECRET_KEY), $request->getMethod(), (string)$request->getBody(), ($request->getHeader('Content-Type') ?: [''])[0], $request->getHeader('Date')[0], $request->getUri()->getPath() . ($request->getUri()->getQuery() ? '?' . $request->getUri()->getQuery() : '')));
        return $request->withHeader(
            'Authorization',
            $this->authorizationHeader(
                self::CLIENT_IDENTIFIER,
                base64_decode(self::SECRET_KEY),
                $request->getMethod(),
                (string)$request->getBody(),
                ($request->getHeader('Content-Type') ?: [''])[0],
                $request->getHeader('Date')[0],
                $request->getUri()->getPath() .
                ($request->getUri()->getQuery() ? '?' . $request->getUri()->getQuery() : '')
            )
        );
    }

    private function authorizationHeader($username, $secret, $method, $body, $contentType, $date, $path) {
        $str = join("\n", [
            $method,
            base64_encode(hash('md5', $body, true)),
            $contentType,
            $date,
            $path
        ]);

        $header = 'Onnistuu ' . $username . ':' . base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $str, $secret, true));

        return $header;
    }

    public function createDocument() {
        $response = $this->client->request('POST', self::API_URL . 'document/', [
                'json' => [
                    'document' => [
                        'name' => 'Test document ' . date(\DateTime::ATOM),
                    ]
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Date' => date('r'),
                ],
                'handler' => $this->authMiddleware($this->clientHandler),
            ]);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 201) {
            echo 'Could not create document';
            return;
        }

        return $response->getHeader('Location')[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message says what you are passing to the method when you are calling it, does not match the method signature. So `$this->clientHandler` must not be an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` then.

Comment: But I am doing that in the constructor?

Comment: You’re doing _what_ in the constructor …?

Comment: $this->client = new Client();
        $this->clientHandler = $this->client->getConfig('handler');

here? In the constructor function

Comment: And …? Whatever you have stored in your config under `handler`, is not the right kind of object your method expects as parameter.

Comment: Ok so I stored the Request GuzzleHttp as an object and tried, gave this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timeme-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:361

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor create add new object `request` of class `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`:

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->request = new Request();
   $this->client = new Client();
   $this->clientHandler = $this->client->getConfig('handler');
}
```

and in your `createDocument` method pass this only:

```
'handler' => $this->authMiddleware($this->request),
```

because your error clearly says
**must be an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`, instance of `GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack`**

Comment: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/timeme-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:361 Stack trace:

Comment: you are overriding `$request` at first line of function `authMiddleware`

Comment: Removed that same isssue.